# How do you submit a form from Django server side?

Tags: django, http, post, paypal

I have a form with some paypal fields and other fields specific to my application. I would like to submit the form to my server, have it process some of the fields and then forward it onto the paypal handler url for payment. If I use the following in my server code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    // Process some form elements

    // Forward on to paypal
    return HttpResponseRedirect("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr")
```

The problem is that the original form does not get posted with the redirect. How can I make this into an HTTP post with the original form so that they are redirected to Paypal and able to login and complete payment?

Answer (score 0):

you can use http.client to make POST requests. Below is a link to the documentation and examples.

http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/http.client.html

Comment: But it would need to be a redirect as the use will have to interact with the Paypal page right?

Answer (score 0):

I think that also accepts GET requests, meaning that you can pass that form data in the url. So you should be able to do along these lines...

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    // Process some form elements
    // Forward on to paypal
    return HttpResponseRedirect("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?%s" % "&".join(["%s=%s" % (key,value) for key,value in request.POST.iteritems()]))
```